# Order DynamoDB paginated Boto scan by order

Tags: sorting, pagination, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have clear code for ordering a DynamoDB scan by ascending or descending using the

```
response = table.query(
    ScanIndexForward=False # true = ascending, false = descending
)
```

argument. Likewise I have the boto paginator for paginating responses using the following:

```
paginator = dynamodb.get_paginator('scan')

response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
               TableName=table.table_name, 
               PaginationConfig={"MaxItems": 25, "PageSize": 1}
            )
```

But I am unable to find an optional argument or method to do both. The order returned by the paginator class appears to be random.

Is there a way to order the notifications by ascending or descending and then split into paginated shards?

I have investigated the optional arguments passed to the paginator scan in the documentation but ScanIndexForward is not an optional argument on SCAN and there is no ASC or DESC option in the conditions that can be passed to ScanFilter.

The table is created within the python CDK with the following partition and sort keys:

```
dynamodb.Table(
            self,
            "NotificationsTable",
            partition_key=dynamodb.Attribute(
                name="_id", type=dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING
            ),
            sort_key=dynamodb.Attribute(
                name="Date", type=dynamodb.AttributeType.NUMBER
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot order a Scan operation as it spans multiple partition keys, each pk will return at random, but in order by its accompanying sort-key. Your original request was a `Query` with `ScanIndexForward`, this only returns a single partition key ordered by the sort key.

Comment: Thank you again for your assistance. Is there a way to change the paginator to a type of dynamodb.get_paginator('query') and then simply return all results? This would let me paginate and use the scanIndexForward argument?

Comment: Yes, use https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Paginator.Query